# Ping over Trunk Port Juniper

Tags: routing, vlan, juniper, layer3, ping

Let's say I have one vlan on one switch and another vlan on another switch (2 EX2200 Juniper). I have a trunk between the two switches on which both vlans are members. What do I need to do to allow the two vlans to communicate in terms of layer 3 stuff? What routing config needs to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Configure an integrated routing and bridging (IRB) interface](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos15.1/topics/example/RVIs-qfx-series-example1.html) on one of the switches.